# Group and sum the columns that are not in the lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, sum

I have a `df` data frame with columns with the following pattern: `#number - letter` and I want to add in a new column `other` that makes the sum of the columns that are not in `letter_table1` and `letter_table2`:

```
TEXT, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I
a,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
b,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
c,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
d,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
e,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
f,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
g,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
h,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
i,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
j,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
```

for instance :

```
tableau_lettres1 = [H]
tableau_lettres2 = [I, J]
```

How can I do that? For the moment I have tried:

```
        df_sum['others'] = df.loc[:,~df.isin(tableau_lettres1, tableau_lettres2)].sum(axis=1)
```

as well as:

```
        df_sum['others'] = df.loc[:,df.drop(tableau_lettres1, tableau_lettres2)].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: please share your dataframe data and input output as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `tableau_lettres1, tableau_lettres2` are lists, you need to join them to one list, and get the other column names like:

```
df_sum['others'] = df[[col for col in df.columns.tolist() if col not in tableau_lettres1 + tableau_lettres2]].sum(axis=1)
```